# How to resolve ssl error associated with spring-ws-core

Tags: spring, web-services, ssl

This is the error I am getting when I am using springframework for creating a client, Let me know why I am getting this error,I think it is related to ssl connection, Please let me know your suggestion to stop this error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: Connection reset; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:545)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:386)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:380)
    at com.eoi.oraclecrm.inbound.census.service.OracleCRMCensusDataService.QueryCrm(OracleCRMCensusDataService.java:40)
    at com.selerix.enrollment.service.QueryHandler.QueryRecord(QueryHandler.java:43)
    at com.selerix.enrollment.service.SelerixServiceTest2.main(SelerixServiceTest2.java:57)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:930)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.java:1116)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1973)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1735)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1098)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.CommonsHttpConnection.onSendAfterWrite(CommonsHttpConnection.java:114)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.send(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:47)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendRequest(WebServiceTemplate.java:624)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:587)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:539)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: The server closed or some middlebox closed the connection during the SSL handshake. Might be some deep inspection firewall, might be a bad server configuration, might be wrong TLS version, might be missing client certificate .... - this means it is impossible to say based on the current information what is wrong. Please offer a way to reproduce the problem for others (i.e. which public server), add packet capture to narrow down the problem, show error messages on the server side or similar things.

Comment: Basically the program is going through some records and doing it successfully but after some time it is popping up this error

Comment: If it is only happens sometimes it might be the server restricting how often a client can connect, for example to reduce potential DOS attacks. Or the server might simply be overloaded. Look at the server side for more information.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich  Can you tell me how to find out what ssl or tls version the program is using?

Comment: I have to get 120000 records from the system, I can't afford to stop for every 3000 records,So first I want to see whether I am using the correct protocol they mentioned to me and later I want to check if it is with timeout error

Comment: Do a packet capture and look at the SSL handshake with wireshark or similar. Then you will see which protocol and cipher the server agrees on.

Answer (score 0):

As @Steffen Ullrich already commented, it seems like a server restriction to avoid attacks. You will have to contact the team in charge of the server and negotiate a solution. E.g. whitelist your IP for a couple days, use another massive loading method, etc.